# Add new rows for rows that meet a specific condition in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

Be the following dataframe in Python:

| ID | direction |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | IN |
| TCV | OUT |
| XYV | IN |
| TCV | IN |
| XYV | OUT |
| AAA | IN |

I want to define a method that receives an ID and a direction value as parameters and modifies them according to fixed values specified internally in the function. For example:

```
# Returns the resulting dataframe
df = change_dataframe(df, 'TCV', 'AAA', 'IN')
# Modify only rows with ID equal to 'TCV' and direction attribute value equal to 'IN'. 
# Change the ID from TCV to AAA (specified by parameter) and the direction value 
# from 'IN' to 'OUT' (binary option).
```

The resulting dataframe is as follows:

| ID | direction |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | IN |
| TCV | OUT |
| XYV | IN |
| AAA | OUT |
| XYV | OUT |
| AAA | IN |

I hope you can help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean a **Pandas** dataframe. This should solve your problem:

```
def change_dataframe(df, search_id, new_id, direction):
    condition = (df['ID'] == search_id) & (df['direction'] == direction)
    new_direction = "OUT" if direction == "IN" else "IN"
    df['ID'] = df['ID'].mask(condition, new_id)
    df['direction'] = df['direction'].mask(condition, new_direction)
    return df
```

Comment: Doesn't work because my dataframe has more columns. ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,5) (5,5) (2,)  How can I adapt it if in addition to the ID and direction columns, I have other columns?

Comment: Ok, I have edited my code to address this issue.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, sorry, I think your solution gives problems with datetime columns.

Comment: Datetime column? Which one is it - "ID", "direction" or some other column? What error do you get?

Comment: Another column contained in my dataframe. ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True

Comment: Edited again. Try now.